# How can I parse the package from java code given as a String?

Tags: java, package, libraries

I have a `String` in a simple Java program:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your input was: " + input);
    }
}
```

And I need to parse the package for `Scanner`:

```
java.util.Scanner
and any other matching packages
```

I don't want code as an answer, rather an explanation how to do it, ideally without an IDE.
I have to be able to code with the basic Windows Editor without automatic package importing. A *simple* java program needs to make these imports for me.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parse the package for Scanner"?

Comment: You can't. When you get that source code, you don't know for sure it's `java.util.Scanner` and not some unknown `somebody.wrote.a.Scanner`. IDEs usually search the whole build path to look for classes named `Scanner` and if there is more than one, ask the user which one to use.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I want to do the same as an IDE, but ion my own.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I go through the code and collect all the classes/objects as Strings (Already done). In this case I collect {"String", "Scanner", "System"}. And now I need to resolve the packages these objects need, so that I can compile the program via "javac Test" in the console.

Comment: @Dev_bySimon, how do you know `Scanner` is from `java.util.Scanner` and not from `foo.bar.Scanner`? If you had imports as well, you could do some parsing.

Comment: Well, it's not a trivial task. First, you need to define your dependencies - basically the same things that will be passed in the classpath to the `javac` command, plus the Java runtime itself. Then you'll need to search through all of the above for all the classes. Then it's just a matter of matching the last name.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I want to figure out, what to import. So like if you type in your favorite IDE and you type Scanner for the first time. A popup shows and you select, which Scanner class is the correct one. I want to get all the possible packages to import.

Comment: Then look at the previous comment. You have to scan the classpath, find all available classes, match their names to what you're looking for and make a list of them.

Comment: input.split(".")

Answer (score 0):

// Get package name and print it

```
Package pack = YourClassName.getClass().getPackage();
String packageName = pack.getName();
System.out.println("Package = " + packageName);
```